# C# MsSql Bulk Update

Tags: c#, sql-server, updates, bulk

What is the more effective way to implement bulk update from a collection?
I implemented the insert with SqlBulkCopy but how can I implement Bulk Update?

Thanks

Comment: can you share some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a 'bulk update' - all update statements in SQL run 'in bulk'.

You would just use SqlBulkInsert as you have to insert to a staging table, then run the update from there, like

```
UPDATE [live]
  SET [SomeColumn] = [staging].[SomeColumn]
FROM [dbo].[TheTable] live
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TheTableStaging] staging
  ON live.[SomeKey] = staging.[SomeKey]
```